# “Is this the best you got?” in German

Tags: phrase-request

How would you say:

> Is this the best you got?

in German? It’s supposed to have a condescending tone.

Comment: Welcome to German Language SE. As such phrases tend to have no perfect equivalent, can you tell us, which aspects you want to convey and which situation you have in mind?

Comment: Anybody who is around my age will probably immediately recognize "Ist das alles?" http://youtu.be/fmmoeCbOzdQ

Comment: *Ist das wirklich alles?* Damn, I saw Troja in German a while ago.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

As always it depends on the context :)

If *this* relates to a thing (like a set of cards during a poker game)

> Ist das alles, was du hast? / Mehr hast du nicht?

If *this* relates to a skill (like fighting) you would add *drauf* or *können*

> Ist das alles, was du *drauf* hast? / Mehr kannst du nicht?

If *this* relates to a quantity (like the force of a punch)

> War das schon alles?

Of course the categories overlap in some cases, the parts can be mixed, and neither is totally wrong in most circumstances.

Answer (score 5):

If related to a skill, an alternative (and a combination of options given by Harald) would be:

> Mehr hast du nicht drauf?

Answer (score 4):

You could translate it literally saying:

> Ist das alles was du hast?

I definitely heard that before.

I suggest saying:

> Ist das alles was du kannst?

Answer (score 1):

If it concerns buying something and you are not content with the things the potential seller has shown you till now, a phrase could be:

Haben Sie (wirklich) nichts Besseres?

Don't you have (really) something better?